# Rails: bundle doesn't show installed mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I know may be this is a popular problem but i try many solutions and not get to finish

I try to install mysql in rails with

```
gem install mysql2
```

And I get the result

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.18
1 gem installed
```

But when i try to execute the command

```
bundle show mysql2
```

I get

> Could not find gem 'mysql2'.

All these command execute in my application root directory

What is the problem ?

Comment: for `bundle show` to work, you must include `gem mysql2` in your gemfile.

Comment: Got it thanks it works as you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bundle show` lists the names and versions of all gems that are *required* by your Gemfile, so at first you should add `mysql2` gem to it:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```